# Ошибка с npm start

Tags: node.js, discord

При запуске команды npm start, выдает ошибку

```
[WS => Manager] Manager was destroyed. Called by:
Error: MANAGER_DESTROYED
    at WebSocketManager.destroy (C:\EconomyBot-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:333:54)
    at Client.destroy (C:\EconomyBot-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:237:13)
    at Client.login (C:\EconomyBot-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:226:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:2780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [TOKEN_INVALID]: An invalid token was provided.
    at WebSocketManager.connect (C:\EconomyBot-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:133:26)
    at Client.login (C:\EconomyBot-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:223:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:2780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, 
use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2780) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Токен ввел верный, как это решить?

Comment: Ну значит вы ошиблись и токен всё-таки неверный, что тут ещё можно сказать...

Comment: проверял код и токен на repl.it всё работает, а здесь нет